# How to use Task.WhenAll with c# kubernetes client?

Tags: c#, kubernetes

In my application I am using [c# kubernetes client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp). I need to use Task.WhenAll but everytime namespaces is different and it fails compiling.

```
 var configMap = await client.ListConfigMapForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
 var secret = await client.ListSecretForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
 var service = await client.ListServiceForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
 var pvc = await client.ListPersistentVolumeClaimForAllNamespacesAsync(
                    cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
 var deployment = await client.ListDeploymentForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
 var sts = await client.ListStatefulSetForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken); // var is V1StatefulSetList
 var daemonSet = await client.ListDaemonSetForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken); // var is V1DaemonSetList (and it is same for appropriate namespaces)

 Task.WhenAll(configMap, secret,service,pvc,deployment,sts,daemonSet); // I would like use like this
```

Simply I would like call all async actions as Paralelly or call using Task.WhenAll

Comment: What do you mean by "but everytime namespaces is different"? Please provide *exact details* of what's going wrong.

Comment: By the time you get to `Task.WhenAll` all the previous calls will have completed, one after the other.

Comment: @JonSkeet I mean "var" values it is not static, it is dynamic according to namespace, fpr ex: for deployment it is V1DeploymentList and other ones also different, to be precise "var" is not simple Task even not Task at all

Comment: @Sean yes I would like exactly this approach complete all task, then start my actions after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `await` every call is made and completed before the next runs. So, just remove the awaits and then you have a bunch of `Task`s which you can wait all:

```
var configMap = client.ListConfigMapForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
var secret = client.ListSecretForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
var service = client.ListServiceForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
var pvc =  client.ListPersistentVolumeClaimForAllNamespacesAsync( cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
var deployment = client.ListDeploymentForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
var sts =  client.ListStatefulSetForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken); // var is V1StatefulSetList
var daemonSet = client.ListDaemonSetForAllNamespacesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken); // var is V1DaemonSetList (and it is same for appropriate namespaces)

var result = await Task.WhenAll(configMap, secret,service,pvc,deployment,sts,daemonSet);
```

by `await`ing the `WhenAll` you can wait until all the tasks have completed.

Comment: in this case my actions in below will not work, for ex:  var resultOfConfigMap = configMap.Items.Count;

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov no, at that point it would be `configMap.Result.Items.Count` or `result[0].Items.Count` whichever you prefer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fire off various asynchronous operations and wait form them all to complete then the trick is to not `await` the various calls, as this will execute them one after the other. Instead, you get the resulting `Task` and wait on it. For example:

```
// Start loading config, but don't wait for it to finish
var configTask = client.LoadConfigAsync(...);

// Start loaading stats, but don't wait for it to finish
var stsTask = client.LoadStatsAsync(...);

// Now wait for everything to finish
await Task.WhenAll(configTask, stsTask);
```

Comment: There is no LoadConfigAsync unfortunately

Comment: @ArzuSuleymanov _ I was just using short names so that it formatted better on screen. The concept is the key thing.